# Finding out if panelizer displays are in use

Tags: theming, panels

Does Drupal keep track of exactly *where* panelizer display(s) are in use? Basically, I would like to identify all pages across content types that use a particular display.

Is this information stored? Is there a way to get it programmatically or via the UI?

Comment: If you have admin_devel module enabled, there is a very helpful theme registry viewer at devel/theme/registry. otherwise, I'd look for hook_theme_registry_alter (not sure is that what you really need though)

Comment: I am just guessing but did you try check output of http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_registry/7 ?

Comment: I am able to look through the theme registry but I don't see that it has the info I'm seeking. When I browse it, I see that my template name is in the array but the only info for it is variables, path to template, name, file, type, includes, process and preprocess functions. No paths or page names where it's invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info is not saved in the theme registry, and it's not really available per page or per node. However, it is stored per configured Panels display. Many don't have a title but since I'm using Panelizer, they do have a Panels display ID. Here's a query that returns those:

```
select did, title from panels_display where layout = 'mytemplate';
```

Entity IDs correspond to DIDs in the panelizer_entity table. Once you have queried for the DID you can query for the entity ID using the DID, like so:

```
select entity_id from panelizer_entity where did = 1234;
```

Where you replace '1234' with the DID you got from the previous query.

I have to do that second one for each DID that the first one returns in order to find all entities using mytemplate.